# Convert HDF5 file to JPG image

Tags: python, hdf5, data-conversion, hdf

Is there an easy way to convert a HDF5 file to it's pictorial representation? I'm using HDFView currently to open an HDF5 file and view it as an image, is there a way I can do a conversion in python that mimics this and writes out a picture file?

Comment: I'm not familiar with HDFView, but writing your own script for converting numerical data to an image shouldn't be that hard (using matplotlib, of course). You just need to deliver three values RGB for every pixel. There are also few routines for converting data to RGB representation in matplotlib. If you give me some example data, I could try....